# Knowledge sources for Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm planning to start project with NoSQL for data storage. I was trying to find informations about Cassandra in google but I've found very basic info.
Anyone know where I can find good source of knowledge about Cassandra (planing data structure, working with data (maybe migrating from mysql?) etc)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DataStax has comprehensive Cassandra documentation at http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/index.

"[Cassandra High Performance Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849515123)" is a decent book.  O'Reilly's "Definitive Guide" is actually even worse than a 0.7 book; it's a mix of 0.6, 0.7, and stuff that was cut from 0.7 before release.

Answer (score 1):

The best source of information is the Cassandra wiki at http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/.

There's also an O'Reilly book, *[Cassandra: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449390412)*, but this is for Cassandra 0.7, so is a bit out of date now.

Answer (score 0):

Found this very useful - http://www.datastax.com/events/cassandrasf2011/presentations